# Close and re-launch the app with in the same session in appium python(using v2.0.1)

Tags: python, appium, appium-android

I'm using appium v 2.0.1.

It looks like launch_app and few other functions were deprecated in 2.x. So I used below code. But, it resets the session every time. I want to relaunch the app with in the same session
try:
driver.terminate_app(app_package)
driver.activate_app(app_package)
except Exception as e:
pass

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.